# Google Map in SquareSpace Only visible in Safari and Safe Mode

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, squarespace

I am working on a map inserted in a squarespace iframe but it will only show in safe mode and safari not chrome or IE or edge.

The functionality of the pin drop still works but the map and the zoom functions don't work.

All looked good until I push the site and I see it only works in one browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>LANDMARK LOCATIONS <code>setTimeout()</code></title>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
      var home = new google.maps.LatLng(39.9176356,-99.3003073);

var neighborhoods = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.448114, -96.736079),
new google.maps.LatLng(45.46104, -98.488264),
new google.maps.LatLng(45.460888, -98.498119),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.748639, -88.859211),
new google.maps.LatLng(39.081567, -96.390311),
new google.maps.LatLng(36.545825, -94.317889),
new google.maps.LatLng(37.076475, -94.385972),
new google.maps.LatLng(39.094627, -94.437796),
new google.maps.LatLng(31.0451, -97.165565)
];

var markers = [];
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: home
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
}

function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 20);
  }
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
  }, timeout);
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel" style="margin-left: 42%">
      <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop LANDMarkers</button>
     </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The posted code works for me in chrome: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uLyydwhg/).  I don't understand the `<code>setTimeout()</code>` inside the title tags.

Comment: I am happy to report that SQUARESPACE says the problem is on their end! thank you all so much.